# Eagle schematic to board

Tags: pcb, eaglecad, schematic

I have a circuit with many LEDs, all the same,
VCC-220ohm-LED-GND. Using the Net/Label the schematic is very simple.
Is there a way to have multiple instances of this schematic on the board, and keep the schematic simple, with one net/label schematic?

Comment: you could just show one VCC-220ohm-LED-GND in your schematic, and show a clear label that indicates multiple repetitions ... of course, if you want to generate a PCB then, i think, you would have a problem

Comment: You will have to have multiple instances on the board anyway. You can have one VCC and one ground, with multiple resistors and LEDs branching off. You can also array copy one instance multiple times.

Comment: quote: You can also array copy one instance multiple times.  Thanks! -very much.  I'm just starting, again, with eagle.  I found a little recipe for the component-array ULP.  I will give this a try.